# UITableView with two styles, grouped and non-grouped. is it possible to achieve?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I want to have tableview where table header contains grouped text fields but cells contain non grouped items. 
I have tried to init table view controller with grouped style both cells and header items are grouped but without grouped style header text fields are not grouped. So is it possible to have two different style in one table view or should try to implement two separate table views?

Comment: Why don't you use a custom header?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**No**, it is not possible that one tableview have different style,You can either set **plain or group**.

You have to implement two separate UITableView.

Or you can use Section with Header view.

Comment: Thank you for reply, I have tried view for header section but with no success, so I am trying with two tableviews.

Comment: Using two tableviews, you can have two tableviewstyle in one screen, I found good example here http://iappexperience.com/post/23157217438/how-to-add-multiple-uitableviews-in-the-same-view